# How set value of Select before onChange will execute?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React. In componentDidMount I'm fetching with server => receiving data (competitors) =>  saving data in State. My Select is representation of this data. When Select is changing, ID of Competitor selected is saving in State so it could be send to database after submit. And it's all working. BUT when after page load I don't change anything in select, just submit, this ID is not sending, I know why (onChange not execute), but I don't know how to fix it, I can't set default State manually, because data from database can be different.

This is my State:

```
  state = {
    promotions: [],
    competitors: [],
    draftCompetitorIdToPromote: "",
    draftLevel: "",
    draftDate: ""
  };
```

This is my componentDidMount:

```
 componentDidMount = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/competitors")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ competitors: data }));
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ promotions: data }));
  };
```

This is my onChange function:

```
 compChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      draftCompetitorIdToPromote: event.target.value
    });
  };
```

And this is my select:

```
  <select
        value={this.state.draftCompetitorIdToPromote}
        onChange={this.compChange}
        className="form-control"
      >
        {this.state.competitors.map((competitor, index) => {
          return (
            <option value={competitor._id} key={index}>
              {competitor.name}
             </option>
           );
         })}
      </select>
```

Comment: you have to have a default selected on `componentDidMount` method so that even if user does not select anythign some defauilt is selected and can be sent to the server. If I understand the problem correctly

Comment: Yeah. I think that is the best solution. But I have problem with access to the first item of competitors. When I'm trying to setState and get first item in this way: this.state.competitors[0]._id then I have errors (_id is id of object of mongoose model).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set default value in your state, for this purpose on `componentDidMount` and after data load set `competitors[0]._id` as default value for `draftCompetitorIdToPromote`

```
componentDidMount = () => {
fetch("http://localhost:5000/competitors")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((data => this.setState({
         competitors: data,
         draftCompetitorIdToPromote: data[0]._id,
  }));
fetch("http://localhost:5000/")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => this.setState({ promotions: data }));
};
```

Comment: @TomaszPaczka, please update your question with the json data output from `/competitors` endpoint